# Java JScrollPane Detect Scroll Near Bottom

Tags: java, scroll, jpanel, jscrollpane, jlabel

I've been unable to find anything related to my question on the Internet.

I have a JScrollPane which adds a JPanel, and the JPanel gets populated with JLabels.

Currently, the user scrolls to the bottom of the JScrollPane, and then clicks the 'Next' button.

What I would like to do is to detect when the user is at/near the bottom of the JScrollPane, so that I can then trigger the 'Next' behaviour without any input from the user.

Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an [AdjustmentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/AdjustmentListener.html) registered with your the vertical scrollbar in your `JScrollPane` and take action based on the event value.

Here is an [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Event/DemonstratingtheAdjustmentListener.htm).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did take a look at that page but was unable to make sense of it, Eclipse does not even find the AdjustmentListener class.

Comment: Did you import the class? I've updated with a link to the doc for `java.awt.event.AdjustmentListener`.

Comment: Perfect thanks, I don't know why Eclipse didn't find it before, now I can take a look at that example. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

JScrollBar uses a BoundedRangeModel, and this will accept a ChangeListener -- so you can listen for changes to the scrollbar and respond accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you possibly provide an example? I'm having trouble understanding the documentation.

Comment: @Cristian: there's not much to it. You know how to get the vertical JScrollBar, you know how to get its model via getModel(), you know how to add a ChangeListener, so in the listeer's stateChanged method, compare the model's value with its maximum value. I bet you could code this pretty easily. Why not give it a try?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example showing how to trigger an event when the scrollpane is near the bottom (90% of the height):

```
final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
scrollPane.getViewport().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent event) {
        JScrollBar scrollbar = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
        if (scrollbar.getValue() + scrollbar.getVisibleAmount() > scrollbar.getMaximum() * 0.9) {
            // trigger the 'Next' behaviour here
        }
    }
});
```

Alternatively, the listener can also be added to the model:

```
final BoundedRangeModel model = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getModel();
model.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent event) {
        if (model.getValue() + model.getExtent() > model.getMaximum() * 0.9) {
            // trigger the 'Next' behaviour here
        }
    }
});
```